# In a combobox, how to always showPopUp

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox, popupmenu

I have two `Combobox` who use two `itemstatechanged`, one for the city and the other for the zip code.
When the user type for example `T`, the list is sorted but dont appear when I call `showPopup()`.

The only solution I found was this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
public void run()
{

   box.showPopup();
}
```

But in my case It is not working.

Here an example of my code where i call `showPopup` (is where i sorted the list for the zip code, the city have the same)

```
  if (!listeCodePostauxVisible.isEmpty()) {
    listenerCodePostalActiver = false;
    cbCodePostal.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(listeCodePostauxVisible.toArray()));
    cbCodePostal.setSelectedItem(selectionCodePostal);
    cbCodePostal.showPopup();
    listenerCodePostalActiver = true;
```

l

```
istenerCodePostalActiver=boolean for "blocked" the itemstatelistener called when i select an item

listeCodePostauxVisible=Listed sorted

selectionCodePostal=Element typed by the user
```